# how to pass td as parameter in getJson?

Tags: jquery

```
$("td").click(function(){
    $.getJSON(
        'http://example.com/customer/get_all_vehicle_by_name/?vehicle_name=' + $("td"),
        function(data) {
        }
```

How do I pass the `td` value to the url?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: A `td` element doesn't *have* a "value".  What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).text()` to get the content of `td` and after you get the content of `td` append this to the URL you wish to get JSON for using `$.getJSON()`

```js
$("td").click(function(){
  var tdContent = $(this).text();
  //append this td text in the url
  var url = 'http://192.168.1.4:8080/customer/get_all_vehicle_by_name/?vehicle_name='+ tdContent
  console.log(url);
  //invoke this
  //$.getJSON(url, function(data){});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```